# new to xml: Get children data into php variable

Tags: php, xml-parsing

i need a mean and lean solution for my confirmation form. I retrieve the contact e-mail address from the server XML response. That is as follows:

```
<users>
<User LoginName="test1" Owner="" Alias="" UserType="PAID" ClientType="OBM" 
Quota="10737418240" Timezone="GMT+08:00 (CST)" Language="en" DataFile="1" 
DataSize="1536" RetainFile="0" RetainSize="0" EnableMSSQL="Y" EnableMSExchange="Y"
EnableOracle="Y" EnableLotusNotes="Y" EnableLotusDomino="Y" EnableMySQL="Y" 
EnableInFileDelta="Y" EnableShadowCopy="Y" EnableExchangeMailbox="N" 
ExchangeMailboxQuota="0" EnableNASClient="Y" EnableDeltaMerge="Y" EnableMsVm="N" 
MsVmQuota="0" EnableVMware="N" VMwareQuota="0" Bandwidth="0" Notes="" 
Status="ENABLE" RegistrationDate="1302687743242" SuspendPaidUser="N" 
SuspendPaidUserDate="20140503" LastBackupDate="1302699594652" EnableCDP="Y" 
EnableShadowProtectBareMetal="Y" EnableWinServer2008BareMetal="Y" 
Hostname="123.abc.com">
<Contact Name=""Email="www@qqq.com"/>
</user> 
…
</users>
```

I got as far that i have the following results:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(6) "Company" } 
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(26) "email@address.ext" }
```

Now i need those into variables. I seem unable to accomplisch this. My code get to here:

```
    $request = "http://$SERVER/obs/api/GetUser.do?
    SysUser=$SYSUSER&SysPwd=$SYSPWD&LoginName=$logonname";
    // Execute the API Call and place the XML output in an Array variable
    $response = simplexml_load_file($request);
    // Retrieve the LoginName attribute from the Array
    foreach($response->children() as $child) {   
        foreach($child->attributes() as $data) {
            echo var_dump($data);
        }
     }
```

Any Newbie help would be appriciated. Thank you

Frank

Comment: you apparently already got to SimpleXMLElement holding the email, so what exactly is the problem? How to get the email string out of it? $email = (string) $emailElement;

Comment: `echo var_dump` is redundant. var_dump already does output by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of reading the Name and Email out of your XML:

```
$response = simplexml_load_file($request);

foreach($response->User as $user)
{
    foreach($user->Contact as $contact)
    {
        $name = $contact->attributes()->Name;
        $email = $contact->attributes()->Email;

        echo $name;
        echo $email;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/4QFqx2vD)

Comment: The echo is empty. My response contains:

Comment: @FrankSchuurman check the casing in your XML. Your opening user tag is `User` but the closing is `user`. You need to use whichever casing is in your real XML, in the PHP code - so change accordingly. Other than that the above code should work (see the demo).